# How to run a Python script by adding its path to Environment variables?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, environment-variables

I have a python script at *C:\users\harrypoter\Documents*. (lets assume as *sample.py*).
Now I added Python path(C:\python) and Documents folder path(‪C:\Users\harrypoter\Documents) to *Environment Varialbes* and tried typing in command prompt **sample.py** and **sample** but it saying " sample is not a recognized..."

Where have i went wrong?

Comment: You need to type `python sample.py` into command prompt

Comment: Is your python really located in the folder called `C:\python`? Usually it has the version on the end `C:\Python34` or `C:\Python27`

Comment: No, It's C:\Python

Comment: after adding the python script path did you restart cmd.exe?

Comment: Environmental variable finds the first file on a line. See `assoc /?`, `ftype /?`, and set up python files to open. Then see `Set PATHEXT=%pathext%;.py`. Now just type the filename with or without the extension.

Comment: `assoc .py=PythonFile` then `ftype pythonfile=c:\python\python %1 %*` (%1 may need quotes)

Comment: I don't understand this. Would you like to comment elaborately.

Comment: Just type the three commands. As two of them have help explaining it and I gave directions to the explanation and a perl example.

Comment: As mani said, after modifying the registered environment variables, you need to restart the CMD shell. Only programs that own top-level Windows get notified about changes to the environment (CMD hosts no windows at all), and of those, generally only Explorer actually reloads its environment in response to the notification. So CMD has to be restarted from Explorer to inherit the updated environment.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issues. So include Python PATH in Environment Variables in

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System -> Select Advanced System Settings -> go to Advanced Tab -> Select Environment Variables -> Go to bottom Pan -> Add the python path after ;

After that a restart may be required.

Should be used like **python sample.py** from any path of command path